Equivalent condition for geodesic in $\mathrm{SO}(m)$
Consider the special orthogonal group $\mathrm{SO}(m)$ equipped with the standard left-invariant Riemannian metric
$$g(X,Y)=\operatorname{tr}(X^T Y),$$
where we identify $\mathrm{T}_e\mathrm{SO}(m)$ with $\mathrm{Skew}(m)=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}:X+X^T=0\}$. I wish to show that a $C^2$-curve $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to\mathrm{SO}(m)$ is a geodesic if and only if
$$\gamma''(t)^T\gamma(t)=\gamma(t)^T\gamma''(t)$$
for all $t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. My attempt at a solution is as follows:
As $\mathrm{SO}(m)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, we have that the Levi-Civita connection on $\mathrm{SO}(m)$ is the tangential part of the Levi-Civita connection on $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, which is simply the directional derivative through the standard identification. This implies that
$$\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'(t)=(\gamma''(t))^{\mathrm{tan}}\in\gamma(t)\mathrm{Skew}(m).$$
To determine the tangential part of $\gamma''(t)$ we find an expression for the orthogonal projection onto $\gamma(t)\mathrm{Skew}(m)$. By this answer we know that this is given by the mapping $X\mapsto\frac{1}{2}(X-\gamma(t)X^T\gamma(t))$, and so
$$(\gamma''(t))^{\mathrm{tan}}=\frac{1}{2}(\gamma''(t)-\gamma(t)\gamma''(t)^T\gamma(t)).$$
Rearranging we have that
$$2\gamma(t)^T\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'(t)=\gamma(t)^T\gamma''(t)-\gamma''(t)^T\gamma(t).$$
From this it immediately follows that $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'=0$ if and only if $\gamma''^T\gamma=\gamma^T\gamma''$. As $\gamma$ is a geodesic if and only if $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'=0$, the claim follows.
My question really is whether what I've done is correct or not, and whether there is some alternative way to approach this. I believe it is correct, however I am still not comfortable with the constant identifications of spaces which seems to appear all the time in differential geometry, and as such still doubt my self. Any comments are welcome.

Is $\operatorname{tr}(X^TY)$ actually the euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ restricted to $\mathfrak{so}(m)$.

@Chris yes, that's right
